# PHP Ajax: Perform action when database is updated

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

What I want to do is, when something new comes into the database, it gets the latest value entered and plays a specific song depending on what it says.

For example, on my computer, I run this website. Say somebody else around the world picked up their phone and clicked to play a song, that song would automatically play on all devices running the page. When somebody chooses a new song, the song should change.

I have made several tries at this, mainly trying to use `setInterval` in JavaScript however it just updates and updates all the time as you would expect.

I guess what I really am looking for is a way to track when the database has been updated, any solutions or code examples I can use?

Comment: Keep track of which user's you've "notified" so you don't "notify" them multiple times of the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you right, you can use push notifications.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/

Here's a tutorial how to set up a js client
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client

In this case you won't have to do unnecessary requests to the server to fetch updated. Just send a push notification to the client and do necessary actions on the client side.